# Using two panels in one page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been doing a simple website for my final year project and I want to create a booking system which is using Winforms. I want to book by inserting the number of seats chosen by the customer. the customer will see the first panel when he/she enters the destination and date and then choose the seats after that click ibnext and that will lead the second panel which the customer had to enter the name and phone. but in my case, the second panel never gets fired I debugged one line at the time I have realized the second panel never gets true. I don't what's wrong. please, I need help.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader rea;
    SqlDataReader read;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seattable.Visible = false;
        ibnext.Visible = false;
        txtname.Focus();
    }


    protected void departon_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == "--Select--")
        {
            DepartureTime.Items.Clear();
        }
        else
        {

            DepartureTime.Items.Clear();
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

            conn.Open();

            string strsql = "Select * from TimeTable where Station_name = '" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
            SqlDataReader rea;

            System.DateTime jtime = new DateTime();

            cmd.CommandText = strsql;
            rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DepartureTime.Items.Add("--Select--");
            while (rea.Read())
            {
                jtime = System.DateTime.Parse(rea["Time"].ToString());
                if (departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() == System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString())
                {
                    if (jtime > System.DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        DepartureTime.Items.Add(rea["Time"].ToString());

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DepartureTime.Items.Add(rea["Time"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Destination_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        departon.Items.Clear();
        departon.Items.Add("--Select--");
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.00).ToShortDateString());
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(2.00).ToShortDateString());
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(3.00).ToShortDateString());
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(4.00).ToShortDateString());
        departon.Items.Add(System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(5.00).ToShortDateString());

    }

    protected void DepartureTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connecString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connecString);
        if (DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() != "--Select--")
        {
            seattable.Visible = true;
            DepartureTime.Enabled = false;

            departon.Enabled = false;
            Destination.Enabled = false;
            Source.Enabled = false;
            // display Rent
            con.Open();
            string strsq;
            strsq="Select * from TimeTable where Station_name = '" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'";

            SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(strsq, con);
            cmmd.CommandText = strsq;
            rea = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rea.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rea.Read())
                {
                    litrent.Text = rea[2].ToString();
                    litrent1.Text = rea[2].ToString();
                    litbusnumber.Text = rea[5].ToString();
                }
            }

        }  rea.Close();
        con.Close();

        string strsqle;
        SqlDataReader rear;
        con.Open();
        strsqle= "Select * from States where ((date = '" + departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "') and (Time ='" + DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "')and (Station='" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'))";

        SqlCommand cmo= new SqlCommand(strsqle,con);

     // cmo.CommandText = strsqle;
        rear = cmo.ExecuteReader();
        while (rear.Read())
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 31; j++)
            {
                string s = "s" + j;
                if (rear[s.ToString()].ToString() == "b")
                {
                    ImageButton img = (ImageButton)pnl1.FindControl(s.ToString());
                    img.ImageUrl = "~/img/BoookedSeat.png";
                    img.Enabled = false;            
                }

            }
        }

    }

protected void ibnext_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] str = txtseatnumber.Text.Split('s');
        int len = str.Length - 1;
        littotalseat.Text = len.ToString();
        int z = len * int.Parse(litrent.Text.ToString());
        littotalrent.Text = z.ToString();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
        ///litpnr.Text = rnd.Next(50000).ToString(); to generate unique Ticket numbers 
        litpnr.Text = rnd.Next(50000).ToString() + rnd1.Next(548775).ToString();
        if (len == 0)
        {

            //  Label1.Text = "if";
            pnl1.Visible = true;
            pnl2.Visible = false;
            btnSave.Visible = false;
            Response.Redirect("Selectseat.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            btnSave.Visible = true;
            pnl1.Visible = false;
            pnl2.Visible = true;
            ibnext.Visible = false;
            // Label1.Text = "else";
        }


    }
    protected void seatClick(ImageButton btn)
    {
        ibnext.Visible = true;
        if (btn.ImageUrl == "~/img/SelectedSeat.png")
        {
            seattable.Visible = true;
            btn.ImageUrl = "~/img/AvailableSeat.png";
            if (txtseatnumber.Text.IndexOf(btn.ID.ToString() + ",") > -1)
            {
                txtseatnumber.Text = txtseatnumber.Text.Replace(btn.ID.ToString() + ",", "");
            }
            else
            {
                txtseatnumber.Text = txtseatnumber.Text.Replace(btn.ID.ToString(), "");
            }
        }
        else if (btn.ImageUrl == "~/img/AvailableSeat.png")
        {
            seattable.Visible = true;
            btn.ImageUrl = "~/img/SelectedSeat.png";
            if (txtseatnumber.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                txtseatnumber.Text = btn.ID.ToString();
            }
            else if (txtseatnumber.Text.Trim().EndsWith(","))
            {
                txtseatnumber.Text = txtseatnumber.Text + btn.ID.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtseatnumber.Text = txtseatnumber.Text + "," + btn.ID.ToString();
            }
        }


    }
    protected void s1click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        seatClick(s1);
    }
    protected void s2click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        seatClick(s2);
    }
    protected void s6click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        seatClick(s6);
    }
    protected void s7click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        seatClick(s7);
    }
    // THE REST OF THE S METHODS ARE CUTT IT BCZ OF THE WORD COUNT
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {


        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase1"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection conbal = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conbal.Open();
        string strsqlbal = "select * from Users where (Username='" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmdbal = new SqlCommand(strsqlbal, conbal);

        cmdbal.Connection = conbal;
        cmdbal.CommandText = strsqlbal;

            string[] forsave = txtseatnumber.Text.Split(',');
            string strsql1= "select Count(*) from States where((Date='" + departon.SelectedItem.Text
                     + "') and (Time= '" + DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text
                     + "') and (Station= '" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text
                     + "'))";
        object obj = cmdbal.ExecuteScalar();

        if ((Object.Equals(obj, null)) || (Object.Equals(obj, System.DBNull.Value)))
        {
                    string sqladd = "INSERT into States ([Date],[Time],Station) values('" + departon.SelectedItem.Text
                          + "','" + DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text
                          + "','" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd1= new SqlCommand(sqladd, conbal);

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //ExecuteNonQuery(sqladd);

                }


            for (int j = 0; j <= forsave.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (forsave[j].ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    string strsql2= "Update States set " + forsave[j].ToString() + " = 'b'  where ((Date='" + departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
                       + "')and(Time='" + DepartureTime.Text.ToString()
                       + "')and (Station= '" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
                       + "'))";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strsql2, conbal);
             // cmdbal.CommandText = "<New SQL Command>";
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }






       string strsql3= "Insert Into passengerinfo values('" + litpnr.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtname.Text.ToString() + "'," + txtphone.Text.ToString() + ",'" + Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "','" + Source.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "','" + departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "','" + DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "','" + littotalseat.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtseatnumber.Text.ToString() + "','" + littotalrent.Text.ToString() + "','" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "','Booked')";
        SqlCommand cmd3= new SqlCommand(strsql3,conbal);
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Cookies["destination"].Value = Destination.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["pnr"].Value = litpnr.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["name"].Value = txtname.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["ph"].Value = txtphone.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["jodate"].Value = departon.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["jotime"].Value = DepartureTime.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["seatnum"].Value = txtseatnumber.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["totalseat"].Value = littotalseat.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["rent"].Value = littotalrent.Text.ToString();
            Response.Cookies["busnumber"].Value = litbusnumber.Text.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("print1.aspx");

        }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        lblerror.Text = "Unsufficient Balance to book ticket.";
    //        //}

    //    }
    //}


}
```

Comment: As a heads up, you ideally want to put your SQL objects (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`) into a `using` block.  This ensures they get closed/disposed properly if a method exists unexpectedly.

Comment: Also note creating multiple instances of `Random` one after the other can create duplication.   Have you considered a `Guid` as your random ticket number instead?

Comment: Specifically which part fails to be triggered?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: He does say website and his class is inheriting a systems.Web.Ui.Page so I would assume ASP..

Comment: I thought that only enterprises still using ASP.NET Forms, for their legacy project...

Comment: @Ophaedean Rhythm  Panel two fails the code fails after the seats has been selected.

Comment: @Fabio  it is my final year project am not doing for any organisation.

Comment: @TaW  am new to stack over flow if you guys have any suggestion please share am eager to flow.

Comment: @Daniel: While true this is exactly my point: One has to read the question to find it out. Bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your panels into an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, this means when you change the visibility they should show and hide. Your code should look like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" Id="upPanels" updateMode="conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <panel Id="pnl1" runat="server">
            <!-- contents -->
         </panel>
         <panel Id="pnl2" runat="server">
            <!-- contents -->
         </panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in your code, you need to call the `upPanels.Update();` to update the panel:

```
    if (len == 0)
    {

        //  Label1.Text = "if";
        pnl1.Visible = true;
        pnl2.Visible = false;
        btnSave.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btnSave.Visible = true;
        pnl1.Visible = false;
        pnl2.Visible = true;
        ibnext.Visible = false;
        // Label1.Text = "else";
    }
    upPanels.Update(); //update view
```

Also, you should use parameters for user input in SQL queries, this will prevent SQL injections. [SqlParameter documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)